# What happens to lipoprotein lipase after a sugar only diet?

Tags: biochemistry, metabolism, diet, fat-metabolism, lipids

Insulin increases the activity of lipoprotein lipase thay allows cells to take in lipids from chylomicrons in the blood.

If a person takes a sugar only meal like drinking coke, insulin is released. Will this insulin activate the lipoprotein lipase despite the lack of chylomicron synthesis due to lack of fat in the diet?

Could activation of the enzyme without adequate substrate be of any harm?

Comment: From the name "lipoprotein lipase" I guess that it acts not only on chylomicrons (which are proteins, by the way, not so much different from the  "regular" Lipoproteins) but on VHDL as well, which, like chylomicrons, transport triglycerides to the "arterial wall" to unload. Now, if there is no fat in food, just sugar from coke, the liver will take up sugar then and convert it to triglycerides, of which very few is stored in liver - any surplus is said to be packed into VLDL to be delivered to arterial wall. From there to adipose tisssue - and not to muscle? Maybe that's the basis...

Comment: Highly intersting I find this question: as it is the "starvation" situation that might be basic in nature, thus for understanding. There wouldn't be much cholesterol contained in coke (smile!), what would liver synthesize cholesterol from to go with tryglycerides surely made from sugar, to go with, in the VLDL, off liver?